# Fixed height card aligned to the bottom of the screen

Tags: swiftui

I'm trying to build a view in SwiftUI, whereby:

1. The white card is exactly 62% of the total screen height
2. it is positioned at the very bottom of the screen
3. the HStack with the two buttons is as close to the bottom as possible
4. the title is, say, 20 points lower than the top edge of the card
5. the main text ScrollView takes as much of the space as is left.

Here's a render, but I've not been able to accomplish points 3, 4 and 5.
[image]

And below is the SwiftUI struct. Could you please help me with the positioning/sizing of the elements?

```swift
    struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        
        ZStack (alignment: .bottom) {
                GeometryReader { gp in
                    Image("wave")
                        .resizable()
                        .scaledToFill()
                        .frame(width: gp.size.width, height: gp.size.height*0.38)
                }.ignoresSafeArea()
                
                // Card
                GeometryReader { gp in
    
                    VStack {
                        // Title
                        Text("Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem")
                            .font(.largeTitle)
                            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
                            .bold()
                            .padding()
                        
                        // Main text area
                        ScrollView {
                            Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis sem vel placerat lobortis. Mauris accumsan pulvinar tellus non blandit. Fusce fermentum maximus arcu, eu facilisis mi. Vivamus consequat dapibus augue non feugiat. Vivamus sollicitudin tincidunt hendrerit. Pellentesque in accumsan orci.")
                                .padding(.bottom, 10)
                            
                            Text("In convallis bibendum nisi, in molestie lacus ultricies non. Nullam eget diam id est ultrices porta. Vestibulum pulvinar massa viverra, tincidunt nisi vel, luctus nibh. Suspendisse tincidunt, erat non fringilla auctor, lacus magna vulputate elit, a faucibus nibh justo sed elit. S")
                        }
                        .font(.subheadline)

                        // Button row
                        HStack {
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                                Text("Share")
                            }
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(Color("whitesand")))
                            .tint(Color(.black))
                            
                            Spacer()
                            
                            Button {
                                
                            } label: {
                                Image(systemName: "book")
                                Text("Read more")
                            }
                            .padding(10)
                            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(Color(.purple)))
                            .tint(Color(.white))
                            
                        }
                        .frame(height: 60)
                        
                    }
                    .padding()
                    .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25).fill(Color.white))
                    .position(x: gp.frame(in: .global).midX, y: gp.size.height*0.58)
                    .frame(width: gp.size.width, height: gp.size.height*0.62)
                }

            }
        

    }
}
```

Comment: Look into `Layout`

Comment: I don't suppose you could be a tad more explicit?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/layout

Comment: There's got to be a simpler way than constructing a custom layout. Or am I wrong?

Comment: Not exact, you can use alignments, spacers and frame. `GeometryReader` is being replaced by `Layout`. It is so convenient and more efficient. SwiftUI is a one size fits all UI, Views should adapt to all screens, `pt` specifics should be rare and always accompanied by `ScaledMetric`. 20pt from anything is not a very SwiftUI way of thinking. But now possible with `Layout`

Comment: 20 pts could just as easily be 1%, I don't care about it that much. What I actually need help with is the positining of the card elements: title on top, buttons at the bottom and whatever space is left - allocated to the text. Is this doable without a custom layout?

Comment: Yes. Put the geometry reader at the very top. Base all you percentages on that. The multiple geometry readers are likely your issue. It affects how the views behave

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is one way to do this

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var title: some View{
        Text("Neque porro quisquam est qui dolorem")
            .font(.largeTitle)
            .multilineTextAlignment(.center)
            .bold()
    }
    
    var content: some View{
        ScrollView {
            VStack{
                Text("Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Cras mattis sem vel placerat lobortis. Mauris accumsan pulvinar tellus non blandit. Fusce fermentum maximus arcu, eu facilisis mi. Vivamus consequat dapibus augue non feugiat. Vivamus sollicitudin tincidunt hendrerit. Pellentesque in accumsan orci.")
                    .padding(.bottom, 10)
                
                Text("In convallis bibendum nisi, in molestie lacus ultricies non. Nullam eget diam id est ultrices porta. Vestibulum pulvinar massa viverra, tincidunt nisi vel, luctus nibh. Suspendisse tincidunt, erat non fringilla auctor, lacus magna vulputate elit, a faucibus nibh justo sed elit. S")
            }
        }
        .font(.subheadline)
    }
    
    var buttonRow: some View{
        HStack {
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "square.and.arrow.up")
                Text("Share")
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(Color("whitesand")))
            .tint(Color(.black))
            
            Spacer()
            
            Button {
                
            } label: {
                Image(systemName: "book")
                Text("Read more")
            }
            .padding(10)
            .background(RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 10).fill(Color(.purple)))
            .tint(Color(.white))
            
        }
        .frame(height: 60)
    }
    
    var coverImage: some View{
        Image("test")
            .resizable()
            .scaledToFill()
    }
    
    var card: some View{
        RoundedRectangle(cornerRadius: 25)
            .fill(.white)
            .overlay{
                VStack{
                    title
                        .padding(.top, 20)
                    content
                    Spacer()
                    buttonRow
                }
                .padding(.horizontal)
            }
    }
    
    var body: some View {
        ZStack{
            GeometryReader{ proxy in
                coverImage
                    .ignoresSafeArea()
                    .frame(height: proxy.size.height*0.40)
            }
            
            GeometryReader{ proxy in
                VStack(spacing: 0){
                    Spacer()
                    card
                        .frame(height: proxy.size.height * 0.62)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thank you! This is a very elegant solution, which I'll keep in mind.